# while configuring Joomla 1.5, it shows error

Tags: joomla, xampp

I am using `Xampp 1.8.1`.

It is working fine in joomla 2.5 & joomla 3. but not working joomla 1.5, it is showing errors.

`strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29`

Like the above it shows multiple errors.

Then i have changed the `php.ini` file

set `error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

After changing it shows the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually It's not an error. It's showing just because you(Joomla) are not following best practices. You(Joomla) must follow standards when you code.

Joomla 1.5 kind of out-dated now. Their could be few strict Standards. Anyway when you are using Joomla 1.5 to fix this . But I advise you to not to use obsolete versions of Joomla.

Below will show without strict Standards.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Check out list [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-stop-notice-variable-warnings-errorlogs/).

[Read more](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=271244)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have already changed the above code. i have checked the linked forum. It is very helpful to fix the problem.Correct solution is `display_errors = Off`

Comment: Keep in mind that `display_errors = Off` will stop showing any errors, even fatal one.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have changed the display_errors = Off and using the error_reporting code, it is working now.